Issues with FastAPI and Playwright
I am developing a FastAPI application where I need to fetch and process web content using Playwright. I initially implemented Playwright using its synchronous API, but I encountered a NotImplementedError. I suspect this issue relates to FastAPI's asynchronous nature conflicting with Playwright's synchronous operations. I keep getting {"detail":"Not Found"} when I try to use api and NotImplementedError in logs. I checked for any compatibility issues and made sure that Playwright was updated to the latest version.
Python version: 3.9
FastAPI version: 0.68.0
Playwright version: 1.14.0
Operating System: Windows 11
 > from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
    from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
    from langchain.chains import create_extraction_chain
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    import os
    import logging
    import asyncio
    
    app = FastAPI()
    
    # Load environment variables
    load_dotenv('./.env')
    openai_api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
    
    # Set up logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
    
    # Initialize Playwright browser outside the function, asynchronously
    browser = None
    
    async def get_browser():
        global browser
        if browser is None:
            playwright = await async_playwright().start()
            browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        return browser
    
    async def fetch_page_content(site: str) -> str:
        browser = await get_browser()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto(site)
        page_source = await page.content()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
    
        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
            script.extract()
    
        text = soup.get_text()
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        data = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
        await page.close()
        return data
    
    @app.get("/extract/")
    async def extract_information(url: str):
        try:
            page_content = await fetch_page_content(url)
            llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo", openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
            structured_schema = {
                "properties": {
                    "company_name": {"type": "string"},
                    "contacts": {"type": "string"},
                    "industries_that_they_invest_in": {"type": "string"},
                    "investment_rounds_that_they_participate/lead": {"type": "string"}
                },
                "required": ["company_name"]
            }
            extraction_chain = create_extraction_chain(structured_schema, llm)
            extracted_content = extraction_chain.run(page_content)
            return extracted_content
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("An error occurred", exc_info=True)  # Logs the full stack trace
            error_message = f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
            if not error_message.strip():  # Checks if the error message is empty
                error_message = "An unspecified error occurred, please check the logs for more details."
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=error_message)
    
    @app.on_event("shutdown")
    async def shutdown_event():
        global browser
        if browser:
            await browser.close()
            logging.info("Browser closed.")


How are you calling your endpoint? {"detail": "Not found"} indicates that you're either not calling the correct endpoint or that you're making requests back to the same API on a path that doesn't exists. async vs sync shouldn't play into it.
